# Sed help: string match

Tags: regex, sed

I have a few systems I where I need to modify the /etc/fstab.  The fstab contains

```
/var  /var  ext3 default,nodev,nosuid 1 2
/var/log /var/log  ext3 default,nodev,nosuid 1 2
/var/log/audit /var/log/audit  ext3 default,nodev,nosuid 1 2
```

I need to modify the /var entry removing the nodev mount option.  I'd like to use sed but cant' figure out how to modify that exact line.  Everything I've tried modifies all lines containing /var.

Would appreciate any help as I keep banging my head against the wall.

Thanks,
Bert

Comment: Can you specify which var entry it is you are trying to remove please?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `/var` followed by a space. Try something like

```
sed -e '\=^/var =s/,nodev//'
```

Comment: sed '/^\/var /s/nodev,//'

Comment: Wow that was fast and awesome! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Another sed pattern:

```
sed 's/\(\/var .*\)\(,nodev\)/\1/g' /etc/fstab
```